# Probably simple but confusing assignment error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, assignment-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char gradesList[5];
    gradesList[2] = "X";
    printf("%c", gradesList[2]);
}
```

When I try to run this code I get these errors:

Incompatible pointer to integer conversion

Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Comment: "X" (double quotes) is a pointer to  a string. 'X' (single quotes) is a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign a `char` not a `pointer to a string literal`. Use `'` instead of `"`

```
gradesList[2] = 'X';
```

---

In C string literals are represented using double qoutes, i.e. `"`. And `char` are represented using single quotes, i.e. `'`.

Since you have declared `gradesList` as a `char` array. And are trying to assign a pointer to a string literal, you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Anything inside double quote is considered as string.

you should use :

```
gradesList[2] = 'X';
```